# Browser object references for Chrome, Safari or Opera?

Tags: browser, object, reference, byte-order-mark

I was able to find the browser object references for Firefox and IE...

Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference

IE: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533054(VS.85).aspx

But, I am unable to find the object references for the other popular browsers. I assume that Safari and Chrome have a similar object structure (since they are both based on the WebKit engine). I also assume that Opera generally uses properties defined by Firefox/IE (just to be compatible with those browsers)...

Do those browsers have object references somewhere online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see one for Safari / Webkit:

[WebKit DOM Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/WebKitDOMRef/index.html)

However, it seems to consist largely of stubs, seems very lovelessly produced, and:

> Important: This is a preliminary document. Although it has been reviewed for technical accuracy, it is not final.

Comment: @Šime yeah! Although really largely consisting of stubs. Maybe it gets better if we click the "this was not helpful" link on every page :)

Comment: I like the way it list all the objects in one page. Nice overview. (Although I get the same overview with `console.log(window)`.